# Need to block Google bot, Bing bot and clients with null User Agent by giving forbidden error 403 using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Need to block the user agent from `.htaccess` file with forbidden error. But this effect had to work only with Google, Bing and where there's no user agent at all. This doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (Google|Bing||onlytogivespace) [NC]  
RewriteRule (.*) - [F,L]
```

I wrote this but for the null user agent it doesn't seem to work.

Need help please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (Google|Bing||onlytogivespace) [NC]  
> RewriteRule (.*) - [F,L]
> ```

This will block *every* user-agent. Because the regex in the `RewriteCond` directive is checking whether the user-agent *contains* "" (nothing) - not that it is equal to an empty string. This regex will successfully match every string/user-agent, so will block everything.

To match an empty user-agent, you would need to change the regex to something like: `(Google|Bing|^$|onlytogivespace)`. Note the `^$` to match an empty string.

Additional notes:

- You don't need the `NC` flag on the `RewriteCond` directive. You know that Googlebot is always `Googlebot` and bingbot is always `bingbot`.
- No need for the `L` flag on the `RewriteRule` directive when using `F`. `L` is implied in this instance.
- `(.*)` is not necessary, since you don't need to explicitly match the URL-path and you don't need the backreference.
- Not sure what the `onlytogivespace` is for?

So, this could be rewritten:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (Googlebot|bingbot|^$)
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: DocRoot, YOU'RE THE KING. I have to accept your answer because works perfectly. ;)

Comment: DocRoot onlytogivespace was only for adding an other position in list of and show that I had left a blank space 4 a RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}. "Note the ^$ to match an empty string" -> Now I know. Googlebot blocked and bingbot too. (.*)  removed. About "RewriteRule (.*) - [F,L]" noted what u've written thank u.